# @Test method are not able to inject with multiple classes in TestNG class

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have created a Maven Project with TestNG classes. In TestNG.xml I have given the suite name . I have used multiple browsers Chrome and Firefox to run parallel. Just with setup class and one more class it works fine but when I include multiple classes with `@Test` annotation I will get an inject error and will gives an error.

I will provide the code which i have tried

Setup.java

```
    if (browser.equals("Firefox")) {
          /*the path of the gecko driver is set*/
          System.setProperty("firefoxpath");
          drfirefox=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
          drfirefox.setBrowserName("firefox");
          drfirefox.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        } else {
          /*the path of the chrome driver is set*/
          System.setProperty("chrome path");
          drchrome=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
          drchrome.setBrowserName("chrome");
          drchrome.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        }
logintest_valid.java 
@Test
public static void valid_logintest ()throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

 }
@Test
 public static void valid_test ()throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {   

    }
```

I am getting error as:

> Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [valid_test] with [class org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities].

Expect to run both test cases valid_logintest and valid_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you have a function somewhere in your project which looks like:

```
@Test
public void sometest(DesiredCapabilities caps) {  
}
```

This is not correct way of parameterising [TestNG test methods](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG), you should remove this [DesiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) argument from the method annotated with [@Test](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)

If you want to pass an external argument to the method annotated with `@Test` you should be using [`@Parameters` annotation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)

Comment: Thank you so much code works perfectly fine now . when i changed my methods to non-static and removed the DesiredCapabilities argument from the method annotated with @Test code is working fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'dsay `@Test` annotation should be on non-static methods.

Comment: Thank you so much code works perfectly fine now . when i changed my methods to non-static and removed the DesiredCapabilities argument from the method annotated with @Test code is working fine. Thank you so much